# Flipping the limits the of the integral.

Tags: integration, physics

If my initial point is $a$ and final point is $b$ and there is a function $ f(x) $ continuous in this interval. I have to calculate the integral $$I= \int_ {a}^{b} f(x) dx~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)$$ Now, if I want my $b$ to be the lower limit and $a$ to be the upper limit, then by the property of definite integral $$ I= - \int_{b}^{a} f(x) dx~~~~~~~~~~(2)$$Here comes a misconception, in this equation (2) can I say that $b$ is the initial point. I mean in my actual problem I defined $b$ to be the final point but due to some mathematics I got $b$ in a place where it should be considered the initial point.
I myself reasoned that although $b$ may be the starting point but what I'm doing going in opposite direction as earlier and this may cause problem in vector integrals.
Let's assume $\mathbf{F}$ is a force of some kind and $d\mathbf{x}$ is the displacement and I have to calculate the work done from $ a $ to $ b$, then $$ W = \int_{a}^{b} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{x}~~~~~~~(i)$$ 
$$W= -\int_{b}^{a} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{x}~~~~~~~(ii)$$  In the equation $(i)$ my force and displacements were in same directions (just assume that this was the scenario, that a force is in direction from $a$ to $b$) and in equation $(ii)$ force and displacement would be in different directions if I were to take $b$ as the starting point.

So, my question is can we treat $b$ as the initial point or will it only be the final point, because flipping the limits has caused the minus sign to take care of all things. I mean what will be the work, will it be $$ - (U_b - U_a)$$ or $$ - (U_a - U_b) $$ U being the potential energy and subscripts show the particular point of $U$

Thank you any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\int_{a}^{b} {f(x)dx} = F(b) - F(a)$. ($\int {f(x)dx} = F(x) + C$)
So, $\int_{a}^{b} {f(x)dx} = F(a) - F(b) = - (F(b) - F(a)) = -\int_{a}^{b} {f(x)dx}$

Please imagine we're thinking about areas, not "directions".

Comment: I request to please write thing using $$ sign before and after the mathematical expression as that would make it easy to read. I'm not able to read your equations.

Comment: My question was basically about that work, will the work gonna be $W_b$ - $W_a$ or $W_a$ - $W_b$

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) like the OP has done.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for late.

Consider

$\int f(x) d x$ = $F(x) + C$.

I=$\int^b_a f(x) d x$=$F(b)-F(a)$

I'=$\int^a_b f(x) d x$=$F(a)-F(b)$
$=-(F(b)-F(a))$=−I

We're thinking of areas.

The work will be −(−).
We can treat  as the initial point.
Why don't you treat it?

I referred to this cite https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-01sc-single-variable-calculus-fall-2010/unit-3-the-definite-integral-and-its-applications/part-a-definition-of-the-definite-integral-and-first-fundamental-theorem/session-50-combining-the-fundamental-theorem-and-the-mean-value-theorem/.

Could you read?

Comment: Which video is your problem on?

Comment: I didn't understand you're talking about physics. I did explain the fundamental theorem of integration.

Comment: You gave a link: 'I referred to this'. However that page has three videos and a worked example. Where are you referring to?

Comment: I referred to three of these Accompanying Notes (PDF) to check the fundamental theorem of integration.

Comment: Oh, that's fine.

Comment: You want to say that we cannot do  "negative work", is that right?

Comment: I know we can do negative work. I was just confused on where you referred to.

Comment: Oh this is my mistake.

Comment: I still don't understand what your problem "Flipping the limits the of the integral" is .

Comment: Why the work will not be $-(U_b - U_a)$ ? I mean the first integral says this only.

Comment: The first integral says −(≠ −(−)).The last integral says −(−). This is the same thing. I think you made a careless mistake.

Comment: @MENZIES I don’t mean to be rude, but if you don’t understand what’s my problem then you shouldn’t answer or comment, that’s very logical.

Answer (score 0):

On the contrary, in your second form of the integral of differential work $$-\int_b^a\mathbf F\cdot\mathrm d\mathbf x,$$ the negative sign is not due to the fact that the force is now going in opposite direction. If you think of the parameter as time, then what you've done is *not* flipping the interval from $[a,b]$ to $[b,a]$ as you think, but rather from $[a,b]$ to $-[b,a],$ which is the same as before, only written differently.

Thus, whereas you can think of the force now working from the end of the path to its beginning ($b\to a$), the $-$ sign would undo this effect, and you'd still have the same value as before. So this is still equal to $$\int_a^b\mathbf F\cdot\mathrm d\mathbf x.$$

Comment: **the negative sign is not due to the fact that the force is now going in opposite direction**.  When I said that the negative sign is due to the opposite direction of force?.

Comment: My question was: when we are moving from $b$ to $a$ isn't the force and displacement gonna be in opposite directions? I assumed in the question that force is acting along the line from $a$ to $b$

Comment: @adeshmishra In response to your first question here check the $6$th paragraph of OP, where you discuss equations (i) and (ii).

Comment: @adeshmishra In response to your second question here, I already addressed this in my answer above. If you think of $[a,b]$ as a time duration, then going from $b\to a$ means traversing the same path in reverse. The force field is not depending on time. Thus, the minus sign undoes the opposite work you get now, to give the original value.

Comment: Minus sign appeared due to flipping. And now if we take $b$ as the starting point then the force will be negative to, I mean $\mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{x}$= $-F\times dx$

Comment: Let me try onece more to explain myself. When we move from $b$ to $a$ the force which I mentioned will do negative work (is this clear?) now this negative value of dot product will be canceled due to the minus sign of the integral and we would get $$ \int_{b}^{a} F dx $$ which gonna be equal to $$ - (U_a - U_b) $$ which is opposite of the original work.

Comment: @adeshmishra No, the force is the same as before, since it's not varying with time. What's different now is the displacement, which is opposite to the one before. But the minus sign will correct this back to give the previous value for the work.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that flipping the limits of the integrals works when the integrand in a function and not a vector or a vector dot product. $$ \int_{a}^{b} \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{x} = \int_{a}^{b} F~dx ~cos0 = \int_{a}^{b}F~dx$$ Now if we flip the limits then we won't need to bother about the directions anymore because we have already taken that into our account $$ -\int_{b}^{a} F~dx$$ and this gonna equal as before.